# How i can create url from .phtml in magento

Tags: magento

I want in `magento` create link as it. From .phtml file. I am can't find method for did it

```
magento/index.php/quotes/index/create/id/1/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Mage::getUrl('quotes/index/create', array('id'=>1));
```

Comment: @ArthurYakovlev. If it helps, accept the answer. Don't leave loose ends.

Comment: don't worry. You can accept an answer in 7 minutes. And you appvote if good question)